# AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'add'? I do like in django website but got this error

Tags: django, many-to-many, models

```
for item in data:
    category_id = item['category_id']
    del item['category_id']

    category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)

    code = item['code']

    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(pk=code)
    except:
        article = Article(**item)
        article.save()

    # at this point I have the article & category, but the next
    # statement throws me an error:
    category.articles.add(article)
    category.save()
```

The error is:

```
   AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: Are you using a through model? if so .add and .create will not work.

Comment: Use `category.articles.set(category.articles.all() | article)` works on my scenario.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

JamesO is correct - it looks like your Category.articles field has a through relationship. Assuming that your models at least *resemble* the following

```
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    author = models.CharField()
```

then to add an `Article` to a `Category` you must

```
m = Membership(article=article, category=category, author="Dan TM")
m.save()
```

Note - we can't tell what the `through` field is called, so `Membership` is a guess, inspired by the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)